# I Can't Select Specified Cols on CI4 With Model

Tags: model, codeigniter-4

I'm developing a system with CI4 and unfortunately when i try to find on documentation any method to get specific column with model, i don't find anything, that is correct ? This wont exist ? Why ?

Comment: provide more information. What do you want to use and what you do to get the effect you want.

Comment: @KaRoLeQ I want, using db model, make a select specifying the cols, for example: `SELECT col, col, col FROM table` but on code

Comment: That's absolutely not correct; this is exactly what a `select` statement does: selects a column. I suggest you read through the documentation (and probably brush up on relational DBs in general) https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/models/model.html